# Removing a low predictive column before or after train/test split

Tags: feature-selection

Based on what I found from the other posts I should always first split the data into train/test set and then perform feature selection to prevent information leakage. Here's the part that I don't understand:

if I only remove the low predictive column from the train set, then my test set would have one more column than my train set. It doesn't make sense to me to build a model based on `n-1` variables and then test it on a dataset with `n` variables.
Shouldn't I remove the column before splitting into train/test?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two important aspects:

1. Having a clean modelling *strategy*, e.g. selecting and preprocessing features via cross-validation. This does not involve the test set.
2. Having a clean model "pipeline". Such pipeline applies a model to fresh data, including data preprocessing (e.g. integer encodings, bring columns in the right order etc.). This is simply a question of *programming*.

If aspect 1 says: don't use column $x$, then aspect 2 deals with physically dropping $x$.

Both aspects are inherently important in practice and both can easily go wrong! So it is good to invest time in these things :-).